# Express.js POST method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I'm trying to make a discussion-based Node.js/Express-app and I'm working on the page to create a discussion. I was just testing if my discussion controller file was linked, but everytime I click the button to POST my form, it doesn't do anything.

my pug (view), called 'createDisc.pug'

```
extends layout
block content
    h1 Create new discussion
    form(action='', method='post')
    div
        label(for='title') Title
        input#title
    div
        label(for='desc') Description
        input#desc
    div
        input(type='submit', value='Create')
```

my router, called 'createDisc.js'

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var disc = require('../controllers/disc');

router.get('/discussion/create', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('createDisc');
});

router.post('/discussion/create', disc.createDisc);

module.exports = router;
```

my controller called 'disc.js' where I'm just trying to send 'test' to my console

```
exports.createDisc = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('test');
};
```

my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

const db = require('./controllers/db');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

mongoose.connect(db.url);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/', require('./routes/createDisc'));

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: Where are you using `.post()` hook?

Comment: I changed it, the router.route now says, router.post, which I originally planned to do @Baruch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned `/discussion/create` as your `GET` route and linking it to the express router like:

> ```
> router.get('/discussion/create', function (req, res, next) {
>     res.render('createDisc');
> });
>
> router.route('/discussion/create', disc.createDisc);
> ```

So in reality, you are enabling the route something like:

`GET /discussion/create/discussion/create`

Please try with `.post()` hook and use it like:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('createDisc');
});

router.route('/discussion', disc.createDisc);
```

**Reference:** http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

**Tip:** Please refer to this link for making more meaningful routes. https://github.com/squareboat/api-guidelines#http-methods

## Update #1

Currently, in your HTML(pug) form, you have `action=''`, this means your form is making request to `POST /`.

Please change the action value to `action='/discussion/create'` and try again.

## Update #2

I have made a trimmed down version of your code(without view or db), and it's working perfectly. you can see code [here](https://gist.github.com/raghavgarg1257/84a6997e0ae73425c72c4332d47fa24b).

Routes to test are:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/discussion/create

POST http://localhost:3000/discussion/create
```

## Update #3

In your pug file, your indentation is wrong because of which the input fields are not enclosed inside the form tag. You had an empty form.

```
extends layout
block content
    h1 Create new discussion
        form(action='/discussion/create', method='post')
            div
                label(for='title') Title
                input#title
            div
                label(for='desc') Description
                input#desc
            div
                input(type='submit', value='Create')
```

This will work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response, I accidentaly copied my version with '.route', but I meant '.post', I changed it in the original post above. I think I still need to render the /discussion/create with a GET route? I just need the form to post, so that I can see the console.log('test') working, but now it still does nothing when I submit the form with the 'Create' button.

Comment: still doesn't do anything if I change the action to '/discussion/create'

Comment: Ok thank you, I installed the files and the GET-route http://localhost:3000/discussion/create works perfectly fine, but how do I get to the POST-route?

Comment: I believe both the routes are working in the gist. please try to make a post request to the route `/discussion/create` using postman.

Comment: Nice, thank you, postman indeed makes it work on your files, I'll try it out on my project and maybe I can find the problem that way.

Comment: So, I tested it with postman and the routes and controller are functioning as they should do, so I'm pretty sure the problem is in the pug file, because the button should activate the POST-process, shouldn't it?

Comment: Of course, wow, how did I overlook that for so long, thanks for all the help @Raghav Garg

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the form to be like this :

```
form(method='post', action='./create')
```

And see if it works

Comment: please include your router

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work, my router should be included in the post above?

Comment: that's all I have in it, for now, I just want to see if the disc.js file would respond and do the console.log